# Enumerate CouchDB _changes longpoll connections/feeds

Tags: couchdb, monitoring

CouchDB may have many open requests to _changes with option longpoll. Is there a way to get a list of these requests?

The _active_tasks request seems not to include any information about longpoll _changes requests.